# Show context-menu on mouse down event

Tags: windows, windows-10, mouse, context-menu

On Linux (Fedora 24, MATE desktop), when I right-click something, the context-menu shows up right after I press the mouse button. I then keep holding it, move the pointer over to the option I want and release the mouse button to choose that option.

On Windows, the context-menu only appears after I release the button (mouseup event). So I have to right-click (mousedown, mouseup) and them left-click to choose some option. Here again the action only starts when I release the mouse button.

Is there a way to make the Windows behavior more similar to how it works on Linux so the whole thing feels more agile?