# Disable FireFox select context menu item on RMB release?

Tags: firefox

FireFox takes ('clicks') the context menu item under the mouse (if applicable) when the right mouse button is released after opening the menu on press.

As a result, I frequently accidentally navigate 'back' instead of opening the menu (visibly) at all, since I must slightly move the mouse down and to the right before releasing.

I'm developing the habit of always holding down RMB and moving to the entry I actually wanted before releasing, but I don't like it.

Is it possible to disable this behaviour, so that only LMB (or at least a *second* RMB click) selects an entry from the context menu?

(This is similar, but is about macOS' system context menu; I am asking about FireFox's context menu, on Linux if relevant: [How to show context menu on mouse up instead of mouse down?](https://superuser.com/questions/1166014/how-to-show-context-menu-on-mouse-up-instead-of-mouse-down))

Answer (score 0):

Ah! This has plagued me for ages; of course I would only find the answer right after asking.. (helpfully there are also context menu config entries *without* the underscore..)

In about:config:

```
ui.context_menus.after_mouseup
```

defaults to `false` (i.e. not after mouse-up, don't wait for it, open on mouse-down). Changing it to `true` fixes the issue, since the menu isn't open for mouse-up to select anything.

I still think it's weird that RMB-up acts like LMB-down if it is open, though. Within the same 'click' too.